# What is wrong with my AlloyEditor UI extension?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, contentful

I've followed [this](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/ui-extensions-guide/) guide to add alloyeditor as a WYSIWYG editor into Contentful and was able to add the extention to my contentful staging space.  I copied the html page from the github [repository](https://github.com/contentful/extensions/blob/master/samples/alloy-editor/index.html) along with the code but the editor does not seem to function as expected.  Specifially when I make changes to the editor I am not seeing the Publish button change to "Publish Changes" so it does not seem to be recognizing the data I am adding to to the editor.  Can anyone tell what is missing in the editor script or recommend another WYSIWYG editor?  I'm using VueJS as a frontend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this extension is just not compatible with rich text, using text such as short text or long text on Contentful resolved the issue and imputed data is now saving.